# How to fix the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have  asp.net web site  with sql server data base. One of my table has about 400,000 records. My problem is that whenever I run my qoerys this error thrown in this line:
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
What is this error ? is it related  to huge records  of my table   or  options of my server.
By the way, my server is localhost.
Is there any one who help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please copy the entire exception into your question including the exception? Can you please include the code that creates the issue (including how the `ds` gets populated)?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you need to set the `CommandTimeout` property

[SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, I would question the size of your dataset if you need to return all 400k records. Perhaps implementing some kind of paging would help reduce the amount of data.

Comment: my qouery is not stored procedure but

Comment: String searchstr = String.Format("SELECT * From my tbl  WHERE sh_p='" + txt_sh_p.Text + "' and radif_mah='" + str5 + "' and noe_pard='" + 2 + "' and radif_dad='" + str8 + "'");

Comment: Use async request to your SQL server. Read how to do it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx